# Bug or Feature in R's version 3.3 class constructing

Tags: r, class, oop, r-s4

Trying to build a new class on the base of an `'ordered'` class, using R.version 3.3.1 tried also on new R-devel 
 `R Under development (unstable) (2016-10-26 r71594) -- "Unsuffered Consequences"`
 
I get an error:

```
> setClass('newFactor', representation = c(tempValue = 'character'), contains = c('ordered'))
Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class “classRepresentation” object: invalid object for slot "slots" in class "classRepresentation": got class "character", should be or extend class "list"
>
```

The same thing works on the stable Version 3.2.5

**EDIT** 
OK thanks @hrbrmstr I understood that R 3.3 does not support using S3 objects inside S4 objects but I am still puzzled.
 This:

```
numWithId <- setClass("numWithId", slots = c(id = "character"),contains = "numeric")
```

should work but this :

```
numWithId <- setClass("numWithId", slots = c(id = "character"),contains = "factor")
```

should not, except it does!

```
>  numWithId <- setClass("numWithId", slots = c(id = "character"),contains = 'factor')
> new('numWithId')
An object of class "numWithId"
integer(0)
Slot "id":
character(0)

Slot "levels":
character(0)

Slot ".S3Class":
[1] "factor"
```

On the other hand this does not work:

```
    numWithId <- setClass("numWithId", slots = c(id = "character"),contains = 'ordered')
Error in makePrototypeFromClassDef(properties, ClassDef, immediate, where) : 
  in constructing the prototype for class “numWithId”: prototype has class “S4”, but the data part specifies class “integer”
```

When I add `list` to the `contains =` it works {I have a feeling that this is not the right way of doing this}

```
> setClass("numWithId", slots = c(id = "character"),contains = c('list', 'ordered'))

> new("numWithId")
An object of class "numWithId"
list()
Slot "id":
character(0)

Slot ".S3Class":
[1] "ordered" "factor" 

Slot "levels":
character(0)

>
```

What is the right way of inheriting an S3 object in to an S4 object?

Comment: I think you need to read up on R class systems a bit more. What you want to do is possible but you're trying to invoke deprecated behavior in a few places and not heeding any of the documentation warnings of mixing S3 & S4 classes. Also, pictures are for plots.

Comment: @hrbrmstr 1. can you refer me to a good  reading that will explain what i am doing that is wrong  2. the picture was only to show that in another version it worked

Comment: 1. `?setClass` 2. respect the contributors & paste & format salient output text extracts vs lazily paste screenshots.

Comment: 1. thanks 2. I will edit my Question

Comment: You have a typo; `"odered"` instead of `"ordered"`

Comment: OMG thank you will check that out

Comment: @JDL thank you, still did not fix my error :(